# Group_concat with SELECT inside

Tags: mysql

I have one table (posts) that each have a `post_id`. I also have a table (tags) that holds a `tag_id` and a name. To tie these together, I have a table (post_tags) which contains a `tag_id` FK and a `post_id` FK.

My goal is to get all post columns, with a concated group of tag_ids (easy, done) and a concated group of tag names (hard, haven't figured this out).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Group_concat(ids SEPARATOR ','),
       (SELECT Group_concat(tags.name SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM   tags
        WHERE  tags.tag_id = ids) ta
FROM   (SELECT post_tags.tag_id AS ids
        FROM   posts
               LEFT JOIN post_tags
                      ON posts.post_id = post_tags.post_id) tb
```

This is very close - it correctly group concats the ids, but it only returns a single tag name. Why is this?

Comment: Are you tying to get this list "per post" or "per person" or "just one big list"?  `also:` I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I'm not clear on what grouping you need, the following should help. This query summarises the tags that belong to each post

```
SELECT
      post_tags.post_id
    , group_concat(tags.tag_id SEPARATOR ',') tag_ids
    , group_concat(tags.name SEPARATOR ',') tag_names
FROM post_tags
INNER JOIN tags ON post_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
GROUP BY post_tags.post_id;
```